# Should instrumental variables abide by the effect hierarchy principle?

Tags: machine-learning, causality, lasso, instrumental-variables

People sometimes include the interactions between their instruments and region/year or the interactions between different instruments in the first stage of a 2SLS regression. I wonder if the effect hierarchy principle applies to the instruments in 2SLS.

I'm asking this question because this [paper](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2977074) selects instruments using LASSO without considering the effect hierarchy principle and ends up selecting a few interaction terms without the main effects. Does this make sense?